# Динамические пиксельные тени на Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, render

Разрабатываем игру на Unity3D. Встала такая проблема: необходимо сделать динамические пиксельные тени, типо таких:
 [image: Пример]

Есть подозрение, что для этого нужно написать для камеры шэйдер, однако я никогда не имел с ними дело, и даже не знаю, с чего начать.

Answer (score 0):

нужно изменить в настройках качества Shadow Projection на Stable Fit и выставь более низкое значение в shadow resolution или попробуй Close Fit и low resolution